# crontab reboot is not working

Tags: bash, scripts, kubuntu, cron, 20.10

I am trying to run my script every time my computer reboot. The easiest way I found is to use crontab.

my crontab file looks like this:
[image]

When I try to check log, I get this
[image]

But the script still don't works.

Any Idea ?

Comment: Is there anything after the final & in your cron entry? I don’t think you need that when run under cron. It looks like it’s not being interpreted as you intended in the log. Try it without. The cron environment is different to that of a user. Not everything you expect is available so check your script for environment variables that may not be present in the cron environment

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue that I’ve also faced in the past. I was able to solve it be using systemd rather than crontab.

If you look at the systemd.service manpage, you’ll see generally how to configure systemd to manage a service. There are likely examples for your system in `/usr/lib/systemd/system` or something similar.

For what you need, the service might look something like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Reboot Processes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/{account}/reboot.sh
Type=simple
User={account}
Group={group}
WorkingDirectory=/home/{account}
Restart=on-failure
```

Put this in a file named something like `/etc/systemd/system/reboot-script.service`. Then run `systemctl daemon-reload` (once, and whenever you change `reboot-script.service` to tell systemd to re-read the configuration), then `systemctl start reboot-script.service` to start the process.

If that works as expected, you can use `systemctl enable reboot-script.service` to make sure it starts at boot.

Some notes:

1. Be sure to change the `{account}` and `{group}` strings in the example above to the proper user/group values for your system
2. `WantedBy` in the Install section tells systemd which "target" (see `man systemd.target`) pulls the service in when you enable it using `systemctl enable`
3. `Restart` defines under which circumstances systemd will automatically restart the service. There are more restart-related options, which you may or may not want to change; see the systemd.service man page.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I use something similar to this to get my backup computer to wake up at a specific time after suspend. For shutdown or reboot the script would go in /lib/systemd/system-shutdown